# Tornado authenticating to MongoDB using Motor

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, tornado, tornado-motor

I made a tornado app that is supposed to run some queries against a mongodb instance running on another machine. To this purpose I have set up mongodb with authentication and users. I have checked that everything works and that I can authenticate to tornado using the Robo 3T app and a small synchronous script that uses pymongo.

This is how I initialize my tornado application:

```
class API(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        settings = dict(
            autoreload=True,
            compiled_template_cache=False,
            static_hash_cache=False,
            serve_traceback=True,
            cookie_secret="secret",
            xsrf_cookies=True,
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media"),
            template_loader=tornado.template.Loader('./templates')
        )

        mongohost = os.environ.get('MONGOHOST', 'localhost')
        mongoport = os.environ.get('MONGOPORT', 27017)
        mongouser = os.environ.get('MONGOUSER')
        mongopass = os.environ.get('MONGOPASS')
        mongodb = os.environ.get('MONGODB')
        mongouri = f'mongodb://{mongouser}:{mongopass}@{mongohost}:{mongoport}/{mongodb}'

        self.client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient(mongouri)
        logging.info('connected to mongodb')
        self.db = self.client.get_default_database()
        logging.info('got mongodb database')
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, url_patterns, **settings)


def main():
    port = 8888
    FORMAT = ('%(asctime)s %(levelname) -10s %(name) -30s %(funcName) -35s %(lineno) -5d: %(message)s')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure(TornadoUvloop)
    app = API()
    app.listen(port)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_exit)
    logging.info('Tornado server started on port %s' % port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Everything appears to run until one of my handlers that actually performs queries against the database is hit. Code from the handler looks like this:

```
      cursor = self.application.db['events'].find(
          find,
          projection
      ).limit(perpage).skip(page*perpage)
      buffsize = 0
      try:
          while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
              message = cursor.next_object()
              self.write(json.dumps(message, default=json_util.default))
              buffsize += 1
              if buffsize >= 10:
                  buffsize = 0
                  yield self.flush()
          yield self.flush()
      except Exception:
          logging.error('Could not connect to mongodb', exc_info=True)
```

This code worked just fine before trying to use authentication but now it raises exceptions and stoped working:

```
017-12-12 13:00:20,718 INFO       root                           __init__                             37  : connected to mongodb
2017-12-12 13:00:20,718 INFO       root                           __init__                             39  : got mongodb database
2017-12-12 13:00:20,723 INFO       root                           main                                 67  : Tornado server started on port 8888
2017-12-12 13:00:25,226 INFO       tornado.general                _check_file                          198 : /Users/liviu/Documents/Work/api_v2/src/api_tmp/handlers/event_list.py modified; restarting server
2017-12-12 13:00:25,469 INFO       root                           __init__                             37  : connected to mongodb
2017-12-12 13:00:25,469 INFO       root                           __init__                             39  : got mongodb database
2017-12-12 13:00:25,472 INFO       root                           main                                 67  : Tornado server started on port 8888
2017-12-12 13:00:28,152 INFO       root                           get                                  266 : now querying database
2017-12-12 13:00:28,214 ERROR      root                           get                                  355 : Could not connect to mongodb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liviu/Documents/Work/api_v2/src/api_tmp/handlers/event_list.py", line 346, in get
    while (yield cursor.fetch_next):
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1055, in _refresh
    self.__collation))
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 892, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 950, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 961, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 99, in send_message_with_response
    with self.get_socket(all_credentials, exhaust) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 168, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 852, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 570, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 486, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 466, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 209, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 477, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/Users/liviu/.venv/api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
2017-12-12 13:00:28,220 INFO       tornado.access                 log_request                          2063: 200 GET /event/list/web?starttime=2017-01-01&endtime=2017-02-03T14:00:00&minlatitude=10&maxlatitude=20&minlongitude=10&maxlongitude=20&minmagnitude=2&maxmagnitude=5&mindepth=10&maxdepth=100 (::1) 67.88ms
```

I was able to find some simple examples on how to log in and authenticate to MongoDB and as far as I can figure, that is exactly how I am also doing it (https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/master/doc/examples/authentication.rst).

Can anybody shed some light on what is going on and how to properly authenticate to MongoDB from an actual working tornado application using Motor?

P.S. I am using Python 3.6, tornado 4.5.2 and motor 1.1.

P.P.S. In the meantime I have discovered that using this as the uri makes it work properly:

```
mongouri = f'mongodb://{mongouser}:{mongopass}@{mongohost}:{mongoport}/admin'
```

In the above, I replaced {mongodb} with the "admin" db. After the client gets connected and authenticated on the admin database, I can proceed to get_database(mongodb) and it will work properly. If anyone cares to more clearly articulate what is going on I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [the mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html) :

> authSource
>
> Specify the database name associated with the user’s credentials.
>   authSource defaults to the database specified in the connection
>   string.

That explains why it works if you specify "admin" as target database.
So in your case you should use:

```
mongouri = f'mongodb://{mongouser}:{mongopass}@{mongohost}:{mongoport}/{mongodb}?authSource=admin'
```